# Stream webcam over network from remotePC & access in opencv (on hostPC)- {Linux env.}

Tags: linux, opencv, video-streaming, gstreamer, rtsp

I have been working on real time image acquisition over network (for my autonomous drone project). Until now, I have been using Gstreamer pipeline (udp protocol) to stream the video both on Sender's(remote) & Receiver's(host) side and it works like a charm (almost real time).

The command is as follows:

(source): [http://www.z25.org/static/*rd*/videostreaming_intro_plab/](http://www.z25.org/static/_rd_/videostreaming_intro_plab/)

**Sender:**

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src ! video/x-raw,width=640,height=480 ! timeoverlay ! tee name="local" ! queue ! autovideosink local. ! queue ! jpegenc ! rtpjpegpay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port= 5000
```

**Receiver:**

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=5000 ! application/x-rtp, encoding-name=JPEG,payload=26 ! rtpjpegdepay ! jpegdec ! autovideosink
```

Now, on the Receiver's end, I have written an openCV videoCapture script. And the objective is to access the video stream in opencv(on host).

Just to confirm if gstreamer is integrated in opencv3.2.0 or not, the following line of code was used to capture webcam stream (connected to host itself) using gstreamer pipeline and it worked:

```
cv::VideoCapture camera0("v4l2src ! videoconvert ! appsink");
```

The issue being, using UDP protocol in gstreamer pipeline to access the stream(from remote) in openCV(host) doesn't works. And online sources suggests to use **'rtsp'** in gstreamer pipeline.

***So, if anyone can help me out with the gstreamer pipeline command for 'rtsp' on both Sender's and Receiver's(to be used in openCV) side, it will be of great help.***

PS: My notion is only Gstreamer can be real-time. Any sort of help will be really appreciated for I am still a noob in this whole gstreamer thing. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this as reference for rtsp along with gstreamer.

https://www.stev.org/post/raspberrypisimplertspserver